# how to stop code execution if the component is inactive in Nativescript Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

My application should send data about the device every 5 seconds, but if I minimize the application and reopen it, or if I just go back to the page and go back, the code continues to run even in the background. When I open the application again, the function of sending data is superimposed on an already working function and the data leaves twice as often and so you can create a function indefinitely

How to solve this problem?

My method:

```
sendDeviceInfo(){
                console.log("1111");
                axios.post('', {
                    device: DeviceInfo.systemManufacturer() + ' ' +DeviceInfo.deviceName(),
                    deviceId: DeviceInfo.deviceId(),
                    appId: DeviceInfo.appVersion(),
                    email: this.email,
                    battery: DeviceInfo.batteryLevel(),
                    batteryCharging: DeviceInfo.isBatteryCharging() === true ? 1 : 0
                });
            }
```

And mounted:

```
this.sendDeviceInfo();
setInterval(this.sendDeviceInfo, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to clear the interval when the component is destroyed. `setInterval` returns a reference you can use to clear it.

```
data: () => ({
    ...yourDataStuff,
    sendDeviceInfoInterval: null
}),

mounted() {
    this.sendDeviceInfoInterval = setInterval(this.sendDeviceInfo, 5000);
},

beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.sendDeviceInfoInterval);
}
```

Comment: Thank! This is exactly what I wanted.